# Why does awk behave differently in terminal vs in a perl script?

Tags: bash, perl, awk

I want to get the first occurance of a file in a directory matching some pattern. This is the command I'm using.

```
ls my/file/path/pattern* | awk '{print $1}'
```

Should my directory contain files pattern1, pattern2, pattern3, etc... This command will only return pattern1. This works as expected in the terminal window.

It fails in a perl script. My commands are

```
push @arr, `ls path/to/my/dir/pattern* | awk \'{print \$1}\'`;
print @arr;
```

The output here is

```
pattern1
pattern2
pattern3
```

I expect the output to only be pattern1. Why is the entirety of the ls's output being dumped to the array?

Edit: I have found a workaround doing

```
my $temp =  (`ls path/to/my/dir/pattern* | awk \'{print \$1}\'`)[0];
```

But I still am curious why the other way won't work.

Edit: There are a couple of commenters saying my terminal command doesn't work as I describe, so here's a screenshot. I know awk returns the first column of each line, but it should work as I described if only a few files match.[image: awk returning a single match]

Comment: `my $dir = glob '/path/to/glob*';` (Although what do you mean by "first"? First in some sorted order, or will any random result do?)

Comment: I get `pattern1 pattern2 pattern3` from your first example (each on 1 line). And LOL, `awk` inside of perl must be making the perl-ies going insane ;-! `perl` support `print[f]` and `$1`, etc notation. Good luck.

Comment: The `{print $1}` is printing the first field of _each line_, **not** the first line. What are you trying to do here anyway? Why not use `glob` in perl? Please [edit] your question to explain.

Comment: Not an answer, but you could try: `find path/to/my/dir -name "pattern*" -print -quit -depth 1`

Comment: I'm sure I'm not using head -1.

Comment: Also at Tom Fenech: You are right in that it will print the first field of each line, but there is only one line when there are only a few files that match. Does running `\`ls pattern*\`` in perl return one match per line?

Comment: I don't think there's any case where that awk command will give the results you're saying it does.

Comment: @shellter I'm always amazed at how many questions we see asking how to fix calls to awk or sed from perl or python. Makes me wonder what else is going on in those scripts!

Comment: @user3263864 : Please add tag to your question for OS that you are using. Also, while somehow we're both right about this `ls f*` thing, to simplify your problem and move onto a solution, use use `ls -1 f* | awk ...`. Good luck.

Comment: Is your `ls` aliased to `ls -C` or something like that? Run `alias ls` to see. (As an aside, this is just one reason that parsing `ls` output is a Bad Idea™, even in Bash scripts. In Perl, use pure Perl commands like `glob` or `readdir` instead of relying on the behavior of your shell.)

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! When I execute an ls in the term window, the results look like this

```
file1 file2 file3
file4 file5 file6
```

but the perl command

```
my $test = `ls`;
```

stores the results like this

```
file1
file2
file3
file4
file5
file6
```

Since awk '{print $1}' returns matching results in column 1 for each row, running the command

```
ls file* | awk '{print $1}'
```

in perl returns all matches.

Comment: Nothing to do with Perl.  ls puts its output in a single column when called from any script.  This is a good example of why not to use ls.